# Can't quite figure Linux VLANs out

Tags: linux, bridge, trunk

I've spent the better part of 3 days trying to get this simple example working, I can't really find any cohesive information relating to my problem, I guess people *don't* turn Linux hosts into Switches for a reason, it's god awful.

I'm just wanting to set up a VLAN on Router to (linux-switch) Switch which will allow the host to ping the router, I think I need to untag the frames exiting eth1 to the host and also ensure that frames are tagged when received in eth1 (no idea how to do this). Likewise if anyone thinks I'm overcomplicating, point me in the right direction.

[image: Network Diagram]

---

**Troubleshooting logs**

Ping results

```
r1
 ping 12.1.1.10 -c3
  --- 12.1.1.10 ping statistics ---
  3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2039ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.064/0.100/0.122/0.025 ms
 ping 12.1.1.200 -c3
  --- 12.1.1.200 ping statistics ---
  3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2048ms
sw1
 ping 12.1.1.1 -c3
  --- 12.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
  3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2005ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.058/0.088/0.133/0.032 ms
 ping 12.1.1.200 -c3
  3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2027ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.058/0.088/0.133/0.032 ms
```

brctl output

```
sw1
 # brctl show
 bridge name    bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
 br100      8000.1eccded2855b   no      eth0.100
                                        eth1.100
```

IP scheme

```
R1:
 eth0 0.0.0.0
 eth0.100 12.1.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0

Sw1
 br100 12.1.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
 eth0 0.0.0.0
 eth1 0.0.0.0
 eth0.100 0.0.0.0
 eth1.100 0.0.0.0

h1
 eth0 12.1.1.200 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

R1 Routing table

```
# ip r
 12.1.1.0/24 dev eth0.100 proto kernel scope link src 12.1.1.1
```

Sw1 Routing Table

```
# ip r
 12.0.0.0/24 dev br100 proto kernel scope link src 12.1.1.10 
 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.24 
 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.24 metric 100
```

h1 Routing Table

```
# ip r
 12.1.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 12.1.1.200
```

Answer (score 1):

lol, how embarrassing I was so close to the answer, I just needed to add the raw interfaces to the bridge

```
sw1
# brctl show
 bridge name    bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
 br100      8000.1eccded2855b   no      eth0.100
                                        eth1.100
                                        eth0
                                        eth1
```

Afterwards I was able to confirm connectivity between router and host, and also via Wireshark I could see the VID applied.

If this helped you, please upvote the answer

Comment: That smells fishy. Adding the raw interfaces to the bridge would forward the tagged frames without removing and readding the tags, so it would forward all VLANs, not just this specific one.